# R packages for calibration (optimization/minimization) of pricing models

Tags: programming

Let us assume we have observed market prices and try to find (multiple) model parameters in such a way that the model prices are close to the actual prices, i.e. to minimize the difference between the model and the observed prices, quantified e.g. by the mean absolute error or the root-mean-square error.

Along the way, there are various functions that need to be considered to determine the price, and in the end, we calculate the measure of choice.

What are useful packages in R for this type of optimization/minimization problems? In particular, I look for general packages that are not tied to a specific product, e.g. options.

Comment: Hi @edmond, this is a quite general question. You could even say that you want to minimize *any* sufficiently well-behaved function in R. You could give https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/optim a try.

Comment: DEoptim can be slower than gradient-based algorithms, but won't stuck on local minima.

Comment: @LisaAnn In a similar problem related to options I read the following: It turns out that this problem, like many others in finance, is not easy to solve, and gradient-based
methods will likely fail to do the job (Gilli et al. 2019), therefore gradient-based methods do not seem to be very suitable for my case anyway. However, at this time I have not yet found out why this is the case.

Comment: @edmond, you can use DEoptim with a very wide tolerance to get an idea of the feasible region, then plug those parameters as starting value of Levenberg-Marquardt.

Comment: @LisaAnn Thanks, I'll take a look at it. Do you think that this method is also suitable for very computationally intensive problems, where efficient programming will be the key.

Answer (score 2):

R gives you access to a large number of optimization algorithms; see the [Optimization Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/view=Optimization) for a (probably incomplete) list. What algorithm is appropriate will depend on your model, i.e. the objective function and the constraints. If your model is sufficiently well-behaved at least locally, even a standard gradient-based method, restarted from different initial values, may work well. (See [A Note on 'Good' Starting Values](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1620083) for an example; disclosure: I am one of the authors.) Eventually, the only way to find out is to run experiments.

How fast the optimization algorithm runs will primarily depend on how fast your pricing algorithms are. Calibration means repeatedly valuing your trades/instruments with different parameter values, and so any split second you can shave off your objective function will help. That implies that you usually do not want to use "convenient", high-level functions with lots of error-handling and so on; instead, go for bare-bones pricing routines. Also, you'll typically not calibrate a single instrument, but several. Pricing an array of instruments can often be sped up by caching and reusing parts of the computation.

Differential Evolution, as suggested by @LisaAnn in the comments, is in my experience a robust method for such models. It evolves several solutions at once. If the implementation allows it, you can often gain speed by vectorizing your computations, e.g. by evaluating the objective function for all solutions at once (see [Vectorised objective functions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NMOF/vignettes/vectorise.pdf) for examples).

Comment: Thank you very much for the various links and comprehensive information. So would you also suggest to start with a Differential Evolution and then use this for the Levenberg-Marquardt? Let's assume that we want to evaluate the tranches of a CDX index to have a specific example. Or do you have other suggestions in this case?

Comment: My generic advice would be 1) to implement the model reasonably efficiently, so that you have an objective function that provides a goodness-of-fit for particular parameters, and then 2) to  run experiments, such as what happens when you restart a method in `optim`, say, from different starting values. No suggestion can replace experiments.