# Optimizing/maximizing portfolio returns & defining gradient function in R

Tags: programming, portfolio-optimization

I have been searching on this forum and see some similar questions, such as: [R packages for calibration (optimization/minimization) of pricing models](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/59344/r-packages-for-calibration-optimization-minimization-of-pricing-models) , but I believe I have a somewhat different question.

I have some code in R for determining portfolio return metrics (total return, sharpe ratio, etc) over a given time series that is dependent on an input parameter (actually I have multipe input parameters, but I would like to figure this out for one parameter first).  I'd like to get some advice on the best optimization package in R to use for this.  I'm currently trying 'optimx' and 'nloptr', but like to know there is a better package or approach?

First, my input parameter is a constant where I'd like to set my lower and upper bound at 1.0 and 1.5, and then vary the input to produce the maximum total return.  My current input parameter is 1.25, but I'd also like to restrict/define the step size to no more than 0.05.

Second, my objective function is a series of filters and processes to build a portfolio based on the input parameter.  Ultimately the objective function calculates and returns the total return for the portfolio.

Below is the code I have:

```
    library(optimx)
    startx <- 1.25

    testfunc <- function(x) { "For simplicity, I'm leaving most of this objective function out as it's hundreds of lines of code.  But it includes a series of filters and calculations that returns a single number representing total return of the portfolio.  The last calculation of the function is below.
    .
    Ra_AnnRtns <- RaRb %>%
    tq_performance(Ra = Ra_using_weights, Rb = NULL, performance_fun = Return.annualized)

    return(Ra_AnnRtns)}

    anstest<-optimx(startx,fn=testfunc,gr=NULL, hess=NULL, lower=1, upper=1.5, 
    method="L-BFGS-B", control=list(save.failures=TRUE, maximize=TRUE, trace=1))
```

As you can see the gradient and hessian functions are NULL.

This code does work and produces a realistic result, but it is slow.  It is currently taking about 30 mins to solve.  What advice would you have for the following questions?

1. Are there packages other than 'optimx' or 'nloptr' that would be better suited for my situation?
2. If so, I realize that one thing I should do is provide gradient and hessian functions.  Is this correct?  If so, then how do you define a gradient function for my objective function?  Is it somehow just a function of the total return calculation, or is it more complex that that?  Similiar question for the hessian function.
3. How can I define the step size in the optimx function as it doesn't need to be more accurante than 0.05?
4. As you can see, I'm currently using the "L-BFGS-B" method.  Is that a reasonable method to use or should I consider one of the other methods within 'optimx'?

Thanks in advance, and I realize I asked a lot of questions in this post so assistance on any of my questions is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, without more details on the performance metrics and how it is derived, it is hard to come up with any helpful ideas. `optimx` aims at optimizing smooth functions. Is your goal function smooth? What is the dimension of your decision variable? Did you run benchmark tests?

Comment: I did run benchmark tests and function checks and they were admissible. Yes, the function is smooth. The decision variable is a single number....the ann'l return calculated by tq_performance. Yes, I understand it may be hard to recommend ideas without the detailed objective function. It's just too long to include, but here is a summary. The input parameter defines some filter thresholds, then the function performs filters on a large database of financial information to determine a portfolio.  It then calculates the annual return on the portoflio.

Comment: Is there maybe a different package that doesn't require a gradient and hessian function and uses a coarse step and coarse convergence tolerance?

Comment: Did you ever think about putting all data in a structure / table and skipping the database retrieval step?

Comment: If you only have a few parameters, then a grid search may be the right approach. Since a grid search is not iterative, you can run the function evaluations in parallel. See e.g. function `gridSearch` in package `NMOF` https://cran.r-project.org/package=NMOF (which I maintain).

Comment: Enrico, is 10 or 15 parameters too many to use the grid search approach with NMOF?

Comment: That depends on the number of levels at which to evaluate your objective function. Suppose you have 15 variables, and you want to evaluate each variable at 5 levels. Then you'll need 75 objective function evaluations. So computation time is 75 times the time it takes to compute your objective function for a set of parameters (and, if run in parallel, divided by the number of nodes you have).

Comment: I will only be evaluating 1 level at each variable, so this may be useful.

Comment: Follow up question. Using optimx and the L-BFGS-B method does work.  But I'd like to control the amount of fine tuning it's doing to get the optimum solution.  For example my parameter is 1.25 and I do not need to run more iterations to adjust the paramater past 2 decimal points.  Thus, 1.251 is too much.  I want to the optimization to stop/converge after it gets to 1.26 for example.  I feel like this can be managed using control elements and I've tried using "factr" and "ndeps", but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Wild stab... Are you using any for loops or if-statements in your objective function?  R is notoriously slow when it comes to such, and while running the function once may not seem slow, it may scale quite badly when you call it multiple times from the solver.

Comment: I don't have any if statements.  While I don't have any "for loops", I do have map and apply functions.

Comment: When using the gridSearch function in the NMOF package, how do you "tell" the function to return 'NA' (or something similar) if a particular iteration is causing an error?  I want the function to continue until it's finished and ignore those iterations that returned the error.  Right now it is terminating the code and not finishing the gridSearch. Perhaps something with the "safely" function?